# Practice suggestions for Date handling

Tags: database, date, datetime

There is a similar topic before : [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)

What I am trying to ask is related, but different.

What is the suggested practice for Date handling?

I am looking for a more 'logical' date.  For example, business date of our application, or the date of birth for certain people.

Normally I store it as Date (in Oracle), with 0:0:0 time.  This is going to work fine IF all component of my application is in the same timezone.  Coz that date in DB means 0:0:0 of the DB's timezone, if I am presenting my data to user of another timezone, it will easily have problem because, for example, Date of 2012-12-25 0:0:0 London time is in fact 2012-12-24 16:0:0 Hong Kong Time.

I have thought of two way to solve, but both of them have its deficiencies.

First, we are storing it as a String.  The drawback is obvious: I need to do a lot of conversations in our app or query, and I lost a lot of date arithmetic

Second way is to store it as Date, but with a pre-defined timezone (e.g. UTC).  When application is displaying the date, it has to display as UTC timezone.  However I will need a lot of timezone manipulation in my application code.

What is the suggested way of handling Date?  Or do most people simply use one of the above 3 (including the assume-to-be-same-timezone one) approaches?

Comment: Any sharing on this topic? Or is there anything I need to clarify?  Thanks

Comment: Though I am giving the bounty to only one answer, I want to say, in fact every answer worth noticing and is helping.  Thanks for all your sharing.  Every answer is helping me in further thinking about the way to handle.  I believe having the DB in UTC and date stored as UTC seems to be the very basic step to move on, while I may further consider adding extra column of local date if needed.

Answer (score 2):

A date is a way of identifying a day, and a day is relative to the local time zone, that is, the sun. A day is a 24 hour period (although because of leap seconds and other sidereal corrections, that 24 hours is only a very close approximation). So the date of December 5 in London names a different 24 hour period from the date December 5 in New York. One of the consequences of this is that if you want to do arithmetic on dates between different time zones, you can only do so to an accuracy of +/- 1. As a data structure, this is a conventional date (say, year and day offset) and a time zone identified by an hour offset from UTC (beware, there are some 1/2 hour offsets out there).

It should be clear, then that converting dates in one time zone to dates in another is not possible, because they represent different intervals. (Mostly. There can be exception for adjacent time zones, one on daylight savings time and one not.) Date arithmetic between different time zones can't be done ordinarily either, for the same reason. Sometimes there's not enough data captured to get the perfect answer.

But the full answer to your concern behind the question you asked depends on what the dates mean. If they are, for example, legal dates for things like deadlines, then those dates are conventionally taken with respect to the location of an office building, say, where the deadline is clocked. In that case the day boundary follows a single time zone, and there would be no sense in storing it redundantly. Times would be converted to dates in that time zone when they are stored.

Comment: In fact I am not talking about a date being a specific point in time.  Instead, it is more a "logical" date as I mentioned.  For example, in a stock trading system, I may have a "business date".  Even I am placing order on 2012-12-01 12:34:56, I may be still doing business for the date 2012-11-30.  Another example is birthday, we seldom consider the timezone either.  For example, my birthday is 1999-9-9, no matter where the system locate, my birthday is still 1999-9-9, it won't become 1999-9-8 12:00pm if I move from China to US. (It is a different story if I am making a birthday alert :P )

Comment: As I mentioned above, there's no single logical date; it depends upon the application. Birthdays, as you mention, use the convention that the logical date is relative to the timezone of the birth. Deadlines, as I mentioned, are relative to the office of filing. If your goal is to create a generic library, use my suggestion above. If you have a specific application, just use a conventional date, with time zone or not, and document the date convention plentifully.

Answer (score 2):

Using UTC everywhere makes things easy and consistent. Keeping dates (as points in time) saved as UTC in DB, making math on them in UTC, doing explicit conversions to local time only in view layer, converting user input dates to UTC will give quite stable base for any action or computation you need with them. You don't really need to show the dates to the user in UTC - actually showing them in local time and hinting that you may show them UTC gives more useful information.
If you need to keep only the dates (like the birthday, what you've mentioned in comment), explicitly cut such information away (like conversion from DateTime to Date on DB level, or any code-level possibility).
This is sample of good normalization - the same thing you're doing while using UTF over codepages or keeping to the same units doing physical computations.
Using that approach, your code for differing dates will be much simpler. In case of showing the date & conversions between UTC and locals, many frameworks (or even languages itself) give you tools to deal with locals, while working with UTC, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I once designed and lead the build of a real-time transaction system that handled customers in multiple timezones, but were all invoiced on time periods of one timezone.

The solution that worked well for me was to store both the UTC time and the local time on each record. This came after using the system for a few years and realising there were really two separate uses for date columns, so the data was stored that way.

Although it used up a few more bytes on disk (big deal - disk is cheap), it made things so simple when querying; "casual" queries eg the help desk searching for a customer transaction used the local time column and "formal" queries eg accounting department invoice batch runs used the UTC column.

It also dealt with issues of the local time "reliving" an hour of transactions every time daylight saving went back one hour, which can make using just the local time a real pain if you're a 24 hour business.